# Delphi: Problems with TList of Frames

Tags: delphi, frames, tlist

I'm having a problem with an interface that consists of a number of frames (normally 25) within a TScrollBox.

There are 2 problems, and I am hoping that one is a consequence of the other...

**Background:**

When the application starts up, I create 25 frames, each containing approx. 20 controls, which are then populated with the default information. The user can then click on a control to limit the search to a subset of information at which point I free and recreate my frames (as the search may return < 25 records)

**The problem:**

If I quit the application after the initial search then it takes approx. 5 seconds to return to Delphi.  After the 2nd search (and dispose / recreate of frames) it takes approx. 20 seconds)

Whilst I could rewrite the application to only create the frames once, I would like to understand what is going on.

Here is my create routine:

```
procedure TMF.CreateFrame(i: Integer; var FrameBottom: Integer);
var
   NewFrame: TSF;
begin
   NewFrame := TSF.Create(Self);
   NewFrame.Name := 'SF' + IntToStr(i);
   if i = 0 then
      NewSF.Top := 8
   else
      NewSF.Top := FrameBottom + 8;
   FrameBottom := NewFrame.Top + NewFrame.Height;
   NewFrame.Parent := ScrollBox1;
   FrameList.Add(NewFrame);
end;
```

And here is my delete routine:

```
procedure TMF.ClearFrames;
var
   i: Integer;
   SF: TSF;
begin
   for i := 0 to MF.FrameList.Count -1  do
   begin
      SF := FrameList[i];
      SF.Free;
   end;
   FrameList.Clear;
end;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What type is FrameList of? BTW, in ClearFrames you are referring to MF.Framelist inside the for loop. Doesn't look right here.

Comment: Framelist is a TList declared in the Public section of the TMF Main Form.  The MF in ClearFrames is extraneous, but shouldn't cause any problems in itself should it ?  More Belt & Braces...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are taking control over the memory allocation of the Frames you are creating by Free'ing them, so there's no need to provide Self as the owner parameter in the create constructor.  Pass nil instead to prevent the owner trying to free the frame.

Also, don't like the look of your ClearFrames routine.  Try this instead:

```
while FrameList.count > 0 do
begin
    TSF(Framelist[0]).free;
    Framelist.delete(0);
end;
Framelist.clear;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Switched to Owner (nil) and the above and there is still a 10 second difference between exiting after one run or two...

Comment: Have you used FastMM Full Debug mode to inspect for memory leaks? This might point to a problem, which may in turn be the root cause of some problem further down the line.  You can maybe tell this happened to me and it caused a ~10 second delay on exiting from a debugging session.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know why your app is taking so long to do something, try profiling it.  Try running [Sampling Profiler](http://delphitools.info/samplingprofiler/) against your program.  The helpfile explains how to limit the profiling to only a specific section of your app, which you could use to only get sampling results on the clearing or creating parts.  This should show you where you're actually spending most of your time and take a lot of the guesswork out of it.

Comment: A very quick and dirty alternative to profiling is to run under the debugger and whilst the long running operation is occurring, break into execution, pause execution, or whatever it is called. You do this a couple of times and it's like the poor man's sampling profiler. If there is something egregious consuming CPU for no good reason (or even for good reason!) then you usually break into the middle of it and realisation dawns.

Comment: @David: Yes, but since Sampling Profiler is free, and easy to learn and use, there's really not much reason to prefer the "debugger pause profiling" method IMO.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work when I tried it, but I guess I didn't try too hard. I agree that proper tools are worth having but quite often the "debugger pause profiling" method can work in a matter of seconds. Anyway, it was just another option.

Comment: I can't seem to get Sampling Profiler to work - I get a (french) Access Violation when I try and Start Profiling...