# Delphi: OnClick breakpoint problems

Tags: delphi, debugging

Over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649012/delphi-problems-with-tlist-of-frames) I asked a question about the speed of my application creating and destroying a number (25) of frames.

Whilst trying to track down the solution I have created a new version of my application that has the base interface elements on the Main Form and Frame and have run into another problem that I cannot fathom.

In the application the 25 Frames are created on startup.  Then, on a button click, the frames are destroyed and recreated.  In the full application the frames will be populated with different information on each click, whilst in the test application the frames are just recreated.

**Problem**

Having placed a Breakpoint on the OnClick procedure of the Reload button I am seeing increasingly long times to trigger the break.

In the last set of testing the timings were (from each click) 3s, 10s, 13s, 20s, 25s.
As far as I can tell everything in the Load procedure has completed before I click and reload.

I suspect that the above, rather than the Frames themselves, is the root of the other issue.

Any suggestions?

**Update**
I have identified that the problem is with the Delphi Debugger somewhere.  Without the breakpoint reaction from the button is much more what I'd expect.  There is also a large degree of slowdown when placing a breakpoint onClick in another Project.

I have tried to "Repair" the install - any other options?

Dan

Comment: Is this a standard TButton? Do you have TTimers or threads running? Try inserting a line in OnClick that displays a message ShowMessage('Hello'), does the message appear immediately or is the delay still there?

Comment: My guess it that your problem is with your frame, not in the handling of frames. Try to do the same with an empty frame. Use TFrame.Create instead of TFS.Create. If the delay is gone you know that you have some problem with the code in your frame.

Comment: @Ville The button that I'm seeing problems on is on a separate panel to the frames, but the delay occurs before the Show Message.  @Mikeal  will look at the blank frames...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tracked down the problem with the OnClick breakpoint - don't yet know if it solves the problem with the application though.

The issue seems to be that I'd turned on the following setting in the **Tools > Options** menu

The setting of interest was **Debugger Options > Event Log > Messages > Windows Messages**

Hope this helps

Dan